# Preparing for char8_t in C++ 17

Tags: c++

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 16.1 (2019 Community) and am trying to write code which will be "proper" in C++ 2020 which is expected to have a char8_t type which will be an unsigned char.  I define a type like this:

```
using char8_t = unsigned char;
```

Code such as the following:

```
std:string data;
const char8_t* ptr = data.c_str ();
```

does not compile as it will not convert the signed char pointer to an unsigned char pointer without a reinterpret_cast.  Is there something I can do to prepare for 2020 without having reinterpret casts all over the place?

Comment: By the time `char8_t` comes along, there will also be a `std::u8string` specialization of `std::basic_string` for `char8_t`. Don't mix `std::string` and `std::u8string` together when it comes to handling UTF-8 strings.

Comment: "*which will be an unsigned char*" That's not how `char8_t` works. It's a distinct type, different from `unsigned char`, though it can explicitly and losslessly be converted to/from them.

Comment: Just `using char8_t = char;`

Answer (score 3):

[P1423 (char8_t backward compatibility remediation)](https://wg21.link/p1423) documents a number of approaches that can be used to remediate the backward compatibility impact due to the adoption of `char8_t` via [P0482 (char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings)](https://wg21.link/p0482).

Because `char8_t` is a non-aliasing type, it is undefined behavior to use `reinterpret_cast` to, for example, assign a `char8_t` pointer to a pointer to `char` as in `reinterpret_cast<const char8_t*>(data.c_str())`.  However, because `char` and `unsigned char` are allowed to alias any type, it is permissible to use `reinterpret_cast` in the other direction, e.g., `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(u8"text")`.

None of the remediation approaches documented in P1423 are silver bullets.  You'll need to evaluate what works best for your use cases.  You might also appreciate the answers in [C++20 with u8, char8_t and std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833000/c20-with-u8-char8-t-and-stdstring).

With regard to `char8_t` not being a UTF-8 character and `u8string` not being a UTF-8 string, that is correct in that, `char8_t` is a code unit type (not a code point type) and that `u8string` does not enforce well-formed UTF-8 sequences.  However, the intent is very much that these types only be used for UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. The comments and further research has corrected a major misconception which prompted the original question.  I now understand that a 2020 `char8_t` is *not* a UTF-8 character and a 2020 `u8string` is *not* a UTF-8 string.  While they may be used in a "UTF-8 string" implementation, they are not such.

Thus, it appears use of `reinterpret_cast`'s is unavoidable, but can be hidden/isolated to a set of inline function overloads (or a set of function templates).  Implementation of a `utf8string` object (perhaps as a template) as a distinct object is necessary (if such is not already available soemewhere).