# Writing UTF BOM in C++20

Tags: c++20

I had the code

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::string BOM = u8"\uFEFF";  // C2440
    std::ofstream f("utf8.txt");
    f << BOM;
}
```

which worked in C++14 and C++17.

Switching to C++20 now, I get the compiler error [C2440](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2440)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170#c20-u8-literals-are-const-char8_t). UTF-8 string literals seem to have undergone a breaking change.

The MSDN article suggests a `reinterpret_cast`, but I can't do that for a string. (And I really doubt that this cast would be a good idea).

```cpp
std::string BOM = reinterpret_cast<std::string> (u8"\uFEFF");
```

**How do I make my code work without fiddling with the UTF-8 BOM Bytes like 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF? I somehow liked how \uFEFF worked nicely with all sorts of encodings.**

I also tried:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::u8string BOM = u8"\uFEFF";  // ok now
    std::ofstream f("utf8.txt");
    f << BOM;                        // C2679, no matching << operator
}
```

in which case the `u8string` line is fine, but the stream output is not.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55556200/4137916). UTF-8 support in C++20 seems to be... problematic.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: thanks. It looks like I fell into that trap.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the suggestion. Have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833000/c20-with-u8-char8-t-and-stdstring ?

Comment: What about not using neither `u8` nor `u8string`? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TMPErefPq)

Comment: @rturrado: did you try that with a file? It doesn't give a UTF-8 BOM.

Answer (score 0):

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833374/480982) mentioned by [@Bob_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob) will do for my uses.

So my code looks like

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string from_u8string(std::u8string const& s) {
    return { s.begin(), s.end() };
}

int main()
{
    std::string const BOM{ from_u8string(u8"\uFEFF") };
    std::ofstream f("utf8.txt");
    f << BOM << "你好";
}
```